# How to specify a graph to color specific points?

Tags: r, colors, plot, rgl

I'm graphing a matrix in 3d using the **rgl** package in R and was wondering how I can color the points of two important groups. I know the row number of the matrix I am trying to identify with a color.

```
plot3d(my3colmatrix)
```

The points of group A want to highlight are rows: `288, 482, 621, 1304`
and points of group B are rows: `503, 727, 764, 904, 1412 1480, 1555`

Comment: Have you tried using the `col` argument discussed in the documentation? If so, what have you tried and how didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Typically graphing functions in R have a "col" argument which can be given as a vector of colors, one per row.

If you define mycol (my colors):

```
mycol <- rep("black", nrow) # where nrow is the number or rows
mycol[c(288, 482, 621, 1304)] <- "blue"
mycol[c(503, 727, 764, 904, 1412 1480, 1555)] <- "red"
```

You can use the col argument col=mycol to highlight the points that you want to show in a different color.